# IDA change to graph view

Tags: graph, reverse-engineering, ida

Hey Im a very beginner in reverse engineering and i was watching some tutorials on Youtube. I've downloaded ida and noticed that i dont have the same view as the guys on youtube. With the view they have they have a good overview how the functions are linked. So i would be glad if somebody could help me to change it to the graph view.

This is how it does look like in my ide view
[image]

And this is how i want it to look like
[image]

Comment: Just press "Space"

Answer (score 4):

First, you should locate yourself inside a function. Graph View would only be shown by IDA if you are inside functions.

As can be seen from your first screenshot, you are not inside a function. Simply, go to your entry point (`start`) a couple of rows below. You can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Alternatively, choose any of the `sub_****` from the Functions menu to the left.

Then, after you are inside a function, just press <kbd>Space</kbd> and you'll see the the Graph View.